# Bulk `unintern` for renamed exported symbols

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I use packages a lot and the exported symbols often change their names. When I try to recompile the package I get warnings like this:

```
package.lisp:3:1:
warning: 
    MY-PROJECT also exports the following symbols:
  (OLD-SYMBOL1 OLD-SYMBOL2 OLD-SYMBOL3)

See also:
  Common Lisp Hyperspec, DEFPACKAGE [:macro]
  SBCL Manual, *ON-PACKAGE-VARIANCE* [:variable]
--> EVAL-WHEN 
==>
  (SB-IMPL::%DEFPACKAGE "MY-PACKAGE" '("KE") 'NIL 'NIL 'NIL '("CL") 'NIL
                        'NIL '("NEW-EXPORTED-SYMBOL1" "NEW-EXPORTED-SYMBOL2") '("MY-PROJECT") 'NIL
                        ...)
```

I know that I can use `(unintern 'old-symbol1)` to signal the system I don't want to use that symbol anymore. However this is becoming very tedious when there is a lot of renaming.

My questions are:

**1) Is is possible to signal to `sbcl` or `emacs` to `unintern` the old/previously exported symbols automatically?**

**2) If not - is it possible to get all "old" symbols in a variable?**

My plan for 2) is to make a key binding to something like `(apply #'unintern *old-symbols*)`

Comment: If you set `*on-package-variance*` to something like `(list :warn nil :error t)` (see the description for the variable) you'll get an option to drop the symbols.

Comment: This seems to be the right way to go, but I still cannot make it work. I tried setting `:warn` to `nil` and `:error` to `nil`... Any suggestions are welcome...

Comment: You need to set `:error t`. You won't get the restart otherwise.

Comment: But I don't want to get the restart. I want `sbcl` to automatically unexport previously exported symbols so I don't have to press any buttons any time I change a symbol name. :) But even with `:error nil` I still get the restart.

Comment: "But even with :error nil I still get the restart." - Your SBCL seems to be behaving differently from mine then. Anyway, if you don't want to have to press anything, you could try `UIOP:DEFINE-PACKAGE` instead. It seems to just unexport them silently. Personally I prefer to have the error+restart to let me make sure that everything is happening correctly though.

Comment: Whoops. What I meant was that I still get a warning with `'(:warn nil :error nil)`. However now I changed my mind and I will set the `'(:error t)`. At least it is just one key press. I also tried using "uninterned symbols" e.g. `#:symbol` for the exported symbols but it doesn't make a difference. Anyway, can you please write your comment as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the variable `*on-package-variance*` to a list `(:error t)` will give you an error instead of a warning when redefining the package. The error will have a restart `DROP-THEM` to unexport the symbols.

You can add

```
(setf *on-package-variance* '(:error t))
```

to your `~/.sbclrc` to have it always set when starting up SBCL.

Comment: I did that and said to drop-them and recompile that file, but I get that error no matter how times I drop them. Any clues?

Answer (score 3):

First I don't think you want to unitern symbols. Unintern removes them from the package. I think you want to unexport them to avoid the warning. You can do that with the following function

```
(defun unexport-package-symbols (package)
  (do-symbols (symbol package)
    (destructuring-bind (symbol status)
        (find-symbol (symbol-name symbol) package)
      (when (eq status :external)
        (cl:unexport symbol package)))))

;; It takes a package-designator as an argument.
(unexport-package-symbols "MY-PACKAGE")
```

Comment: Make sure that you UNEXPORT from the right package. You have to provide a package argument. Otherwise you unexport from the 'current' package. Same for FIND-PACKAGE. Otherwise you get the STATUS from the 'current' package.

Comment: I wanted to say, FIND-SYMBOL, not FIND-PACKAGE. You'd have to change FIND-SYMBOL in your code, too.

Comment: @PuercoPop There is a `do-external-symbols` function. So the code should look like `(do-external-symbols (symbol package) (unexport symbol package))`

Comment: This function seems to fail because of (some?) symbols inside a `let`. I get `The value xx is not of type LIST` (when trying do destructure-bind). Or maybe only ones inside a `let*`.